# ¿Cómo corregir este NullPointerException al hacer el callback?

Tags: firebase, kotlin, nullpointerexception

Estoy trabajando en Kotlin y firebase obteniendo los datos y para eso llamo un metodo en onviewcreated llamado datos() al cual le almaceno en un modelo lo que pretendo obtener.

Resulta que en primera vez que se obtiene la informacion carga sin ningun problema pero al realizar callback me genera el java.lang.NullPointerException.

¿Cómo podria solucionar este inconveniente?. Dejo un poco de mi código para tratar de mostrar como estoy tratando de hacer las cosas

```
    E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.mundomedicos.fitapp.navigationcomponent, PID: 1733
        java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.mundomedicos.fitapp.navigationcomponent.fragmentosUsuario.AlimentacionFragment.getBinding(AlimentacionFragment.kt:37)
            at com.mundomedicos.fitapp.navigationcomponent.fragmentosUsuario.AlimentacionFragment.access$getBinding(AlimentacionFragment.kt:35)
            at com.mundomedicos.fitapp.navigationcomponent.fragmentosUsuario.AlimentacionFragment$macros$1.onDataChange(AlimentacionFragment.kt:209)
            at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(ValueEventRegistration.java:75)
            at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(DataEvent.java:63)
            at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(EventRaiser.java:55)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:257)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8333)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:603)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

```
    class AlimentacionFragment: Fragment() {
    
    private var calo = "0"
    
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
            datos()
    }
    
    private fun datos(){
            database.reference.child("usuarios").child(user).child("macros")
                .addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener{
                    override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                        if (snapshot.exists()){
                            calo = "0"
                            val mc = snapshot.getValue(Macros::class.java)
                            calo = mc?.kal.toString()
                            if (calo == "0.0"){                          
                                binding.tvrestcalorias.text = calo                  //aqui                            binding.tvrestcalorias.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(requireActivity(), R.color.rojo))
                            }else{
                                binding.tvrestcalorias.text = calo                  //aqui                            binding.tvrestcalorias.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(requireActivity(), R.color.black))
                            }
                        }
                    }
    
                    override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
    
                    }
                })
        }
    }
```

Comment: añade a la pregunta la traza del error; no lo resumas :)